# mysql create a table from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I would like to create a table from another table. I have a table A as follow:

```
TABLE A
id   year   month   value
1    2020   1       5*
2    2020   2       2**
3    2019   5       15***
...
```

And I would like with mysql to create a table from that one into this model:

```
TABLE B
id   year   jan   feb   mar   apr   may  ...
1    2020   5*    2**   7     5     4
2    2019   1     4     3     1     15***
...
```

I can do it with code in php but I would like to do it in mysql so that I can create a migrate file for laravel and this will be managed automatically by the admin.

I know I should post things I tried but as I said, I m more a php coder and I know how to do it in php. I have checked how to create a table from another table but I don't find a solution explaining when multiple records need to fill in a specific record in the new table.

Comment: that is a pivot table you have to make some thing like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/61416286/5193536

Comment: Ok, I ll give it a try, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id, year,
       max(case when month = 1 then value end) as jan,
       max(case when month = 2 then value end) as feb,
       max(case when month = 3 then value end) as mar,
       . . .
from t
group by id, year;
```